# using bootstrap on spring initializr

Tags: html, spring, intellij-idea, jakarta-ee, bootstrap-4

I work on **spring** in intellij, I found a problem using **bootstrap** .. I declared the dependency on **pom.xml** but I did not find it in external libraries

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I don't know what to write on href

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="">
```

Answer (score 1):

WebJars has pretty good [documentation](https://www.webjars.org/documentation#springmvc) on how to use it with Spring. The Web dependencies are made available on the classpath at `META-INF/resources/webjars/`. You need to add a resource handler to have Spring serve the dependencies at a desired location:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
      registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
}
```

Then you can include reference resources at the resource location you specified in the resource handler:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/webjars/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for not _just_ linking to the documentation, but _also_ providing a good explanation along with code samples. This is a good first post.